# Estoy haciendo una actividad que dice así:

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel

Edit. Adjunto el enunciado completo de la actividad y el código que he escrito, tengo la duda con el bucle del punto 7.

**Enunciado completo**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código completo**:

No sale bien cuando lo pongo aquí directamente así que lo he subido a drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lSqPa8neE3LeUa-zwhblhrEsBJ4kTAaS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Observa el **operador de asignación** `=` contra el **operador de igualdad** `==`.

Comment: Te salen todos por la mañana porque el mes es siempre el mismo. Haces un bucle con `i=1`, pero la comparación la haces siempre con `mes`, y no veo que reasignes esa variable a nada más... así que siempre será la misma una vez que entres en el bucle, con lo cual todos tendrán el mismo resultado. Por cierto, una captura del código ***NO ES VÁLIDA***. La próxima vez añade el código SIEMPRE como texto, por favor.

Comment: mes lo tengo puesto como un int, que se supone se ha introducido manualmente antes, la actividad es mas larga, solo que tengo la duda con el final, voy a intentar pasar el código completo y ver si así me puedes ayudar. Ahora lo edito.